# custom field output after the_content

Tags: custom-field, the-content

What I want to do is output a custom field content (which is a button with a dynamic link that's being inserted in the value of the custom field of each posts) right after the_content and before the plugins.

This is the code for the custom field:

```
<div class="button">
  <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Button', true); ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/button.png'; ?>" alt="link" />
  </a>
</div>
```

On wordpress codex I also found this example of how to apply a filter to the_content in order to obtain something similar to what I want. This is the code:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter', 20 );

/**
* Add a icon to the beginning of every post page.
*
* @uses is_single()
*/
function my_the_content_filter( $content ) {
if ( is_single() )
    // Add image to the beginning of each page
    $content = sprintf(
        '<img class="post-icon" src="%s/images/post_icon.png" alt="Post icon" title=""/>%s',
        get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ),
        $content
    );

// Returns the content.
return $content;
}
```

The problem is I don't know PHP and I have no idea how am I supposed to edit the above code to apply on my specific case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer - code to be added in the functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter', 0 );
function my_the_content_filter( $content ) {
if ( is_single() )
{
    global $post;
    $pgLnk=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Button', true);
    $content .= '<div id="button-link"><a href="'.$pgLnk.'" target="_blank">
    <span class="button-link"></span></a></div>';
}
return $content;
}
```

This code was wrote by @Sheikh Heera on stackoverflow.com - [direct link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164789/wordpress-custom-field-output-after-the-content)